# Change UISwitch Image

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I'm creating a toggle feature. Everything is working exactly how I would like it to. My ONLY issue is changing the image to one that's more fitting for my app.

Here's what I have:

https://res.cloudinary.com/dfd4ae1lw/image/upload/v1530126510/Stackoverflow/off_switch.png"

https://res.cloudinary.com/dfd4ae1lw/image/upload/v1530126510/Stackoverflow/On_Switch.png

THIS is what I want:

https://res.cloudinary.com/dfd4ae1lw/image/upload/v1530126510/Stackoverflow/On_Toggle.png

https://res.cloudinary.com/dfd4ae1lw/image/upload/v1530126510/Stackoverflow/Off_Toggle.png

How do change the image of the UISwitch? There must be a way... right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple removed the ability for users to specify a custom UISwitch image in iOS 7, implicitly for policy reasons. So there is no direct way to achieve what you want.

You can simulate it with an NSButton by toggling the `isSelected` state; this is entirely distinct from the `isHighlighted` state that relates to user interactions and the interface designer allows you to specify different images for different states.